# How to send an object by post method with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, slim

As I can send an object by the post method with retrofit, I need to authenticate a user by sending his phone and password to a file that receives the data as an array

I have the following code block

```
private void makeRetrofitCall(String phone, String password)
{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestPost requestPost = new RequestPost(phone,password);

    ApiInterface interfaces = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ResponsePost> responsePostCall =   interfaces.AuthUser(requestPost);

    responsePostCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePost>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePost> call,   Response<ResponsePost> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                ResponsePost rp=response.body();
                Log.d("Respondido", rp.toString());
            }
            Log.d("ERROR>>>>>>>>>>>>>",response.message());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePost> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}
```

my 2 class

```
public class RequestPost {
@SerializedName("Phone")
private String Phone;
@SerializedName("Password")
private String Password;

public RequestPost()
{
}

public RequestPost(String phone, String password)
{
    this.Phone = phone;
    this.Password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.Phone = phone;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.Password = password;
}
}

public class ResponsePost {
@SerializedName("Name")
private String Name;
@SerializedName("LastName")
private String LastName;
@SerializedName("Email")
private String Email;
@SerializedName("Phone")
private String Phone;
```

Response post to retrieve information

```
public ResponsePost()
{
}

public ResponsePost(String nombre, String apellido, String mail,String telefono)
{
    this.Name = nombre;
    this.LastName = apellido;
    this.Email = mail;
    this.Phone = telefono;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ResponsePost{" +
            "Name ='" + Name + '\'' +
            ", LastName ='" + LastName + '\'' +
            ", Email =" + Email +'\''+
            ", Phone =" + Phone +
            '}';
}
}
```

This is my route in SLIM 3 which should receive the data sent by post

```
$this->post('login', function ($req, $res) {
    $um = new UserModel();      

    return $res
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->getBody()
        ->write(
            json_encode(
                $um->Login(
                    $req->getParsedBody()
                )
            )
        );
});
```

How should I define my endpoint ApiInterfface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

String URL = "http://edwineds.com/moviles/public/mobi/";
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
     Call<ResponsePost> AuthUser(@Body RequestPost user);
}
```

Error Logcat android

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)
                                                                        for method ApiInterface.AuthUser
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:667)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:658)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:676)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:616)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:328)
                                                                        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:201)
                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                                        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java)
                                                                        at $Proxy0.AuthUser(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.example.edwin.taxi.Login.makeRetrofitCall(Login.java:129)
                                                                        at com.example.edwin.taxi.Login.access$300(Login.java:25)
                                                                        at com.example.edwin.taxi.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:56)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending the request body as JSON, you should not be using the @FormUrlEncoded annotation. The @Body annotation is enough.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    String URL = "http://edwineds.com/moviles/public/mobi/";
    @POST("login")
    Call<ResponsePost> AuthUser(@Body RequestPost user);
}
```